# JavaFX: Bind bidirectional with NumberConverter

Tags: java, javafx

Consider this:

```
final TextField tfNum = new TextField();
final IntegerProperty intProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

Bindings.bindBidirectional(tfNum.textProperty(), intProp,
    new javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter());
```

When the user types in `-1`, the binding throws exception when the user types in the first character `-`. Is there a way to make the `NumberStringConverter` handle this gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You could use a custom converter though that simply outputs a default value, if parsing fails:

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
StringConverter<Number> converter = new StringConverter<Number>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(Number object) {
        return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Number fromString(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

};
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
Bindings.bindBidirectional(tf.textProperty(), property, converter);
```

---

Alternatively use a `TextFormatter` that only commits on <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the loss of focus and automatically sets the default value if it fails to parse the string:

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();

TextFormatter<Number> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0);
tf.setTextFormatter(formatter);

IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
property.bindBidirectional(formatter.valueProperty());
```

Comment: I asked the question aware of the first approach, and I was wondering when would `NumberStringConverter` be ever useful (since it's part of public API), because I imagined at least 90% of typical use cases to be related to a text input control. The second approach is an eye-opener for me, though. It totally made use of the `NumberStringConverter` and it seamlessly handles it gracefully.